# Bash, if's, reusing variables

Tags: bash

```
if [[ $line == *"option 1"* ]]
then
     CURRENT_OPTION=1
fi

if [[ $line == *"option 2"* ]]
then
     CURRENT_OPTION=2
fi

if [[ $line =~ "What i want" ]]
then            
    if [[ $CURRENT_OPTION -eq 1 ]]
    then
        MEM1=$(awk '/Used heap/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }')
    elif [[ $CURRENT_OPTION -eq 2 ]]
    then
        MEM2=$(awk '/Used heap/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }')
    fi
fi
```

Because CURRENT_OPTION is defined within an if, its value is not correct when checked in the third if. How do I pass it out so that it is?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your use of `$CURRENT_OPTION`.  Values set inside an `if` should be retained outside of it.  I do, however, see potential issues with the way you're using awk.

Comment: Also, this appears to be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12744353/1072112).

Comment: And if `$line` did *not* match option 1 or option 2?

Comment: Can you confirm that `CURRENT_OPTION` is being set to the value you expect *inside* the appropriate `if` statement?

Comment: You're not sending any input to your awk commands -- they will hang while they wait for some input.

Comment: Oh, this is all happening inside a while read line. So the awk is getting input.

Comment: @chepner , yes, CURRENT_OPTION is being set correctly, and the correct part of the if-elif is being triggered.

Comment: Variables do not get retained when you move between shells.  Since you are within the same shell for all of this, the contents of the variable should be good.  It is good practice, however, to not use variables in all caps since you may inadvertently write over a system variable.  If you use all_lowercase_variables or CamelCaseVariables, you won't run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `CURRENT_OPTION` at the top, something like:

```
   declare -i CURRENT_OPTION=0
```

`i` to declare it as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In all of your `if` statements you should enclose the variables in double quotes. If the variable is an empty string (or if the variable doesn't exist) then the if statement will not contain enough arguments and will throw an error.

Here is an example:

```
if [[ $var -eq 1 ]]
then 
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

If `var` is uninitialised, bash will expand the statement to look like this:

```
if [[ -eq 1 ]]
then 
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

There are not enough arguments to make the `if` statement valid here, and bash will throw an error:

```
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `1'
```

By wrapping the variable in quotes, this situation is avoided. This statement:

```
if [[ "$var" -eq 1 ]]
...
```

is expanded to:

```
if [[ "" -eq 1 ]]
...
```

and now the `if` statement has enough arguments (the first one being an empty string) to parse.